# PHP/MYSQL/Keys: Inserting Table into Two Tables Consistently

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have created these tables in phpmyadmin

```
food -->(id, user_id, name, price, description)

ingredient-->(id, name)

food_ingredient--> (id, food_id, ingredient_name)
```

I want `food_id` to match with food.id same with `ingredient_name` and `ingredient.name`

Anyways I want to insert data into `food` and `food_ingredient` at the same time when a user provides `food.name`, `food.price`, `food.description` information.

So I have (after doing some stripping and trimming of user input):

```
INSERT INTO food

(id, user_id, name, price, description)

VALUES 

(NULL,\"$user_id\", \"$name\",\"$price\",\"$food_desc\")"
```

The question is how do I get `food_id` so that I can run something like:

```
INSERT INTO food_ingredient

(id, food_id, ingredient_name)

VALUES 

(NULL,\"$food_id\", \"$ingredient_name\")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/function.mysql-insert-id) function after the the first `INSERT` and store the value in a variable that you can use in the related inserts.